# oci_fetch always return false

Tags: php, sql, oracle, toad

I've made this PHP code :

```
$sql = 'SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM journalists WHERE category = :cat ';
$requete = oci_parse($identifiants, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($requete, 'cat', $_GET['cat']);
oci_execute($requete);
var_dump(oci_fetch($requete));
```

Before make a loop, I wanted to check if the request is correctly executed. But the `var_dump()` always return false.
So, I have tried to make the request manually in Toad for Oracle with the parameter '1' and it works correctly !

So I don't understand what in my code fails.

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `oci_bind_by_name($requete, ':cat', $_GET['cat']);` maybe?

Comment: I've already try it but but it change nothing ...

Comment: Check adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `var_dump(oci_error($requete))` to get the error